# AFRAME GLTF Model Rendering Inconsistently Compared to Expectations

Tags: three.js, aframe, gltf

[What I can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtAY4.png)

I've been integrating a GLTF model into my A-Frame VR scene, but I'm facing a peculiar issue. The model, when rendered in A-Frame, appears overly transparent, making it seem like it's missing internal texture details. This is not the intended look, and it's different from how the model appears in other GLTF viewers.

What I expected is:
[What I want to see(screenshot of three-gltf-viewer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJMiG.png)

My Code:

```
<video id="ar-video" playsinline="true" webkit-playsinline="true" preload="auto"
   autoplay="autoplay" x-webkit-airplay="true" x5-video-player-type="h5" x5-video-player-fullscreen="true"></video>

<a-scene
        embedded
        arjs="sourceType: video; sourceUrl: #ar-video; trackingMethod: best; debugUIEnabled: true;"
        inspector="url: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js"
        vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
    <a-entity id="model" gltf-model="https://csd-self-host.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/bottle-1.gltf" position="0 1 -5"
              scale="15 15 15" rotation="30 0 0"
              visible="true" material="side: double; "></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: I found the cause of the problem, it seems that my AR scene is mixed with the content of the camera, so it is not the same as the clear color background gltf-viewer.